# Difference between CDialog and CDialogEx

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, compare, cdialog

What is the difference between `CDialog` and `CDialogEx`? I decided to use `CDialog` because I can't assign `m_pMainWnd` to Dlg if Dlg is derived from `CDialogEx`.

```
BOOL CPreparationApp::InitInstance()
{
    MyClass2 Dlg; //derived from CDialog 
    m_pMainWnd = &Dlg;
    Dlg.DoModal();
    return TRUE;
}
```

What kind of problems might I have, by not using `CDialogEx` like form wizard was offering?

How to assign `m_pMainWnd` variable derived from `CDialogEx`?

Comment: What type is m_pMainWnd?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CDialogEx` is derived from `CDialog`, so, setting `m_pMainWnd` to a `CDialogEx` derived object should not be a problem.  `CDialogEx` provides the abillity to set the background color or image of the dialog.

Answer (score 7):

`CDialogEx` is used for setting background color, background images on dialog. If you want to set background images or color then your class will be derived from `CDialogEx`.

But, keep in mind that if you are using `CDialogEx`, then you should use methods of that class (like `CreateEx`). And, if you are trying to derive a class from `CDialogEx` and use a `CDialog` method, then you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a case where a menu button was not working properly and the MFC source code recommended to replace `CDialog` by `CDialogEx`:

[CMFCMenuButton does not close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32007682/cmfcmenubutton-does-not-close)

And after I did it, everything worked right!

Answer (score 0):

`CDialogEx` to create a back ground menu, button or they called it dialog box
If you program a button when it pressed to prompt a window frame. To interact with the window frame, u need to use `CDialog`.

This is because `CDialog` directly inherits from `CWnd`.