# CMFCColorButton popup does not close when clicking outside

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a `CMFCColorButton`inside a `CPropertyPage`. When I click the button, the color choice popup comes up. I can select a color and the popup closes, I can get the color etc.. all good. But when I click somewhere else while the popup is open, it doesn't close. Which it should - what's going in?

Comment: Sounds like a parenting issue. Check what parent window pointer you're giving to the button and the popup dialog. The parent of both should be the page.

Answer (score 1):

I know this problem from when you use this special popups in a dialog. You must use CDialogEx instead of CDialog.

CDialogEx uses OnNcActivate with a CDialogImpl class that closes popups.
As I see the same handling is used in CMFCPropertySheet and CMFCPropertyPage.

SO the solution should be using CMFCPropertySheet and CMFCPropertyPage instead of the CProperty... classes.

Comment: With a similar fundament, I solved the problem I referenced on http://stackoverflow.com/a/32009058/383779